# news aggregator website hosting

Tags: php, mysql, load, web-hosting, dedicated

I am building a news-aggregator website based on php and my sql. Very simple code.. I am using a rss parser to parse rss-feeds from different newspaper websites in my country and store the data(news article title, link, summary etc) in a database, and when user visits the website, I just connect to the database and display... And I will run that parser every 30 minutes or so. I am not sure what kind of webhosting should i buy? I have a shared hosting space from goDaddy which i bought for another project which kinda got cancelled... I was thinking of using that one for the start and when the site gets popular I will shift to dedicated host if required. I have 2 questions here:

1. How much load(traffic number) can a shared hosting space support?
2. How difficult will it be to migrated from shared hosting space to dedicated server?

and any other thing i should know ?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends on your hosting provider.
2. Not a lot of effort for the migration: copy your database and your php code, change some minor dns settings for your domain and you are done.

I would go with the shared hosting and migrate to something better as soon as you notice the load is getting too big.